# How do I move an android app to a new publisher name?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app published in Google Play Store using my personal email id. However, we are planning to register as a startup and launch the app under a company name. When I contacted Google about this process, they said I have to remove the old app and publish it again as a new app from the new id. That would mean I will lose all the current users. Is there a way to do it without removing the old app or linking the old app to the new app? Or some way to force the users to download the update from the new publisher link?

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. If it isn't can you suggest someplace where I could get an answer for this?

Comment: I think you can change the developer account name from the console. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps can be transferred to another developer account without any apparent change to the end user. But if you change the app, Id like from android.app.gekkouga to android.app.startup (which is how I think the person you spoke to understood you), then you have to republish the app which by all intents and purposes is a different app, as PlayStore assigns each app a unique url based on the app's unique app id.